# 3-tier development process (MS SQL routines)

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net, 3-tier

In a 3-tier architecture, the middle tier uses ADO .NET to interact with MS SQL.
We have a few development workstations with an own local SQL Express environment to launch middle tier on via integration tests and SpecFlow scenarios.

Database project contains all stored procedures, tables, roles and initial data, can be published to a local DB.

1. If somebody will change db scheme, i will not know, should i republish database scheme to a local db. Is it possible to automate this.
2. What is the best practicies for SQL development with C# and VS in a team: how to organize db scheme, initial data, installation, migration.

I don't see any difference using single db host. Anyway each user will work with his own db, because there can be different branches for different db scheme development

Comment: you should not share the db locally haviing every local machine share their db you need to use one local r db and coonect to it thru network

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look into Version Controlling your Database project. That way, you should be able to keep a history of changes to the database schema which allows you to rollback or merge the changes.

Comment: ANd what is the best practicies (better to use tested products, e.g. by MS)

Comment: You can try using Team Foundation Server (TFS). One thing you need to take note about Database Projects is that they seem to be complex when we need to handle more than one databases in our queries (i.e. cross DB joins). For single database, they seem to be ok.